# How to rewrite 4D linear system if $A = E \otimes F$?

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products, numerical-linear-algebra

Let $\mathbf{A}$ a 4D matrix made from kown $\mathbf{E}$ and $\mathbf{F}$:

$$
\mathbf{A}_{a \times a \times b \times b} = \mathbf{E}_{a \times a} \otimes \mathbf{F}_{b \times b} \label{1}\tag{1}$$

And $\mathbf{B}_{(a \times b)}$ a 2D matrix.
I want to find $\mathbf{X}_{(a \times b)}$ numerically such

$$
\sum_{i=1}^{a}\sum_{j=1}^{b} A_{x,i,y,j} \cdot X_{i,j} = B_{x,y} \ \ \ \ \forall  \begin{cases}x = 1, \ \cdots, \ a \\ y=1, \ \cdots, \ b \end{cases} \label{2}\tag{2}
$$

I can rewrite it as a standard linear system $\mathbf{M} \cdot \mathbf{Y} = \mathbf{C}$, solve it, and put the values of $\mathbf{Y}$ back on $\mathbf{X}$.

$$\sum_{k=1}^{a b} M_{zk} \cdot Y_{k} = C_{z} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \forall \ z = 1, \ \cdots, \ ab \label{3}\tag{3}$$
$$\begin{matrix}k = b \cdot i + j \\ z = b \cdot x + y \\ M_{zk} = A_{x,i,y,j} \\ C_{z} = B_{x,y} \\ Y_{k} = X_{ij}\end{matrix} \label{4}\tag{4}$$

For small values of $a$ and $b$, solving \eqref{3} that is fine.
But for big values of $a$ and $b$ (which is my case), this method is very expensive.

Then, I thought it would be useful to use \eqref{1} to rewrite \eqref{2} as a new form, easier to solve numerically. Can anyone help me?

$$
A_{x,i,y,j} = E_{x,i} F_{y,j} \ \ \forall \ \begin{cases}x = 1, \ \cdots, \ a \\ i = 1, \ \cdots, \ a \\ y = 1, \ \cdots, \ b \\ j = 1, \ \cdots, \ b\end{cases} \label{5}\tag{5}
$$

Comment: Usually, it is not possible to write $A = E \otimes F$ for any $E$ and $F$. However, we could possibly **approximate** $A$ as a product $A \approx E \otimes F$.

Comment: I didn't get it. The equation \eqref{5} has the indicial notation of equation \eqref{4}. I know $\mathbf{E}$ and $\mathbf{F}$, then I can mount $\mathbf{A}$ to solve \eqref{1}

Comment: It wasn't clear to me if you were already given that (5) holds for known matrices $E,F$ or whether you were **trying to find** $E$ and $F$ such that (5) holds. I thought you meant the latter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have an equation that is ultimately of the form
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{a}\sum_{j=1}^{b} E_{x,i}F_{y,j} \cdot X_{i,j} = B_{x,y} \ \ \ \ \forall  \begin{cases}x = 1, \ \cdots, \ a \\ y=1, \ \cdots, \ b \end{cases} 
$$
As it turns out, you can rewrite this equation conveniently in terms of matrix products. In particular, we have
$$
\begin{align}
B_{x,y} &= \sum_{i=1}^{a}\sum_{j=1}^{b} E_{x,i}F_{y,j} \cdot X_{i,j}
\\ &= \sum_{i=1}^{a} E_{x,i} \cdot \sum_{j=1}^{b} X_{i,j} \cdot F_{y,j}
\\ & = \sum_{i=1}^{a} E_{x,i} \cdot [\mathbf X \mathbf F^\top]_{i,y} 
= [\mathbf E\mathbf X\mathbf F^\top]_{x,y}.
\end{align}
$$
So, your system can more simply be written in the form
$$
\mathbf E \mathbf X \mathbf F^\top = \mathbf B,
$$
where $\mathbf E$ and $\mathbf F$ are square matrices. It turns out that this system is solvable with a unique solution if and only if both $\mathbf E$ and $\mathbf F$ are invertible. In this case, the solution is given by
$$
\mathbf X = \mathbf E^{-1} \mathbf B (\mathbf F^{-1})^\top.
$$
If you would prefer to frame the solution without matrix inverses, you could consider the following combination of systems:
$$
\mathbf Y \mathbf F^\top = \mathbf B, \tag{1}
$$

$$
\mathbf E\mathbf X = \mathbf Y\tag{2}.
$$
System (1) is easy to solve: each row $\mathbf y_{i,:}$ of $\mathbf Y$ separately satisfies the equation $\mathbf y_{i,:} \mathbf F^\top = \mathbf b_{i,:}$. Similarly, system (2) is easy to solve: each column $\mathbf x_{:,j}$ of $\mathbf X$ separately satisfies the eqaution $\mathbf x_{:,j} = \mathbf E \mathbf y_{:,j}$.